# Android Crashlytics ndk; values of NdkOut and NdkLibsOut in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, crashlytics

I have integrated Crashlytics, [Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/) into my app, the sdk related crashes are reported successfully.

For the ndk part, i have followed instructions from the blog; [The Wait is Over: Launching Crashlytics for Android NDK](http://crashlytics.com/blog/the-wait-is-over-launching-crashlytics-for-android-ndk?utm_source=Crashlytics%20Customers&utm_campaign=90ed18ae1d-introducing_crashlytics_ndk_5_29_2015&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_3330fdbe2e-90ed18ae1d-97406981), but the ndk crashes aren't being reported. My doubt is, because other parts are sufficiently clear, i'm not providing the correct path for `androidNdkOut` and `androidNdkLibsOut`, as shown in:

[image]

The doubt and question is in my `build.gradle`, here it is...

```
crashlytics {  

    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut //what would be the obj here?
    androidNdkLibsOut 'src/main/jniLibs' //path for my jni libraries  

}
```

please let me know if i should post any other part of the code

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think this Crashlytics feature asumes you are compiling the C code into the .so files as part of your build process. That will generate the "debug and release binaries" that I think are placed in those folders. If you are using pre-compiled .so libraries I think it wont work.  Look at: https://dev.twitter.com/crashlytics/android/ndk "Controlling the paths to debug and release binaries"

Comment: I actually build those through `./gradle` for debugRelease symbols , hope that is not a problem

Comment: Same issue here, will it work with pre-compiled so libs ?

Comment: @Anton it hasn't worked yet, i've raised it in Crashlytics/Fabric support from the dashboard, no replies yet. I'l post it here if there is any progress...pls do the same

Comment: @user2450263 looks like it works somehow for us ... Checkout out this guide - https://fabric.io/downloads/gradle/ndk

Comment: thanks for the feedback,  how?..what did you provide for `androidNdkOut` and `NdkLibsOut` ?

Comment: We kept it empty, try to follow guide which I linked

Comment: thanks for the guide link, thats where their blog link points to, its the one i followed, though i have not left it empty

Comment: @Anton pls post it as an answer, if that works, will help others too

Comment: @Anton i got help from Crashlytics support, and solved that..not by keeping both fields empty, would be posting an answer soon.  Anybody reading this, if stuck, pls mention it in comments, i'l post the answer asap

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT/UPDATE July 7, 2017**

Matt from the Fabric team here with an update to this answer - we just released the Fabric Gradle plugin version 1.23.0 which includes support for automatically detecting the appropriate native library paths when you're using the `externalNativeBuild` DSL with the Android plugin for Gradle version 2.2.0+, so you no longer need to set the `androidNdkOut` and `androidNdkLibsOut` properties. This will work with both CMake and `ndk-build`. Check out more info here: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/ndk.html#specifying-the-path-to-debug-and-release-binaries

---

I could solve the problem after getting help from [Crashlytics/Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/crashlytics) Support, thanking them..this answer.

First, for

```
crashlytics {  

    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut //what would be the obj here?
    androidNdkLibsOut 'src/main/jniLibs' //path for my jni libraries  

}
```

for my app's `build.gradle`, it should have been:

```
crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut 'src/main/jniLibs'
    androidNdkLibsOut 'src/main/jniLibs'
}
```

> androidNdkOut is where your debug binaries are located. This defaults
>   to 'src/main/obj' but you can set in the crashlytics { } if it's
>   different in your project.

a link which contains useful information on the same: [crashlytics knowledgebase; Missing line numbers in native crashes](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/605190-missing-line-numbers-in-native-crashes)

A minor but very useful part was running commands like `uploadReleaseSymbols` with the `--stacktrace` option. Thought its worth the mention as that(uploading release symbols) was also an issue on my side for not receiving the crash reports.

Answer (score 5):

Follow this guide -https://fabric.io/downloads/gradle/ndk. We kept empty both fields (androidNdkOut and NdkLibsOut)

Comment: They sure don't want anyone finding that.

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar problem: I had to add `CrashlyticsNdk` kit at Fabric.with().

```
Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(context)
    .kits(new Twitter(authConfig), new Crashlytics(), new CrashlyticsNdk())
    .debuggable(true)
    .build();
Fabric.with(fabric);
```

you can check `androidNdkOut`, `androidNdkLibsOut` this way.

```
$ ./gradlew -d clean assemble{Flavor} | grep ndk-build
```

and you will find `NDK_OUT` and `NDK_LIBS_OUT`.

Comment: hey, just an update on this, that command does not work on a mac, with Crashlytics and i have used `Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics(), new CrashlyticsNdk());` , it works